# What CSS will change the Eclipse (Juno) tab hover background color?

Tags: css, eclipse, ide, themes, eclipse-juno

CSS Spy does not show any value for the color that is displayed when you hover over a tab (editor, package explorer, console, etc), and I cannot find the property name documented anywhere. The default (very bright off-white) is a problem for me since I'm trying to set up a dark theme.

Either knowing the specific CSS to change it, or knowing where a programmer's reference can be found would be useful.

Comment: will this help? http://blog.sangupta.com/2012/08/change-eclipse-juno-ui-to-match-eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Eclipse but with normal CSS I would do the following:

`.tab:hover {background-color: #yourcolor}` or
`.tab a:hover {background-color: #yourcolor`

`:hover` is the state, when you mouseover the specified object.